# What are my options for a basement floor drain?

Tags: basement, drain

I'm in the process of finishing my basement and I'm trying to figure out what to do about the existing floor "drain" by my furnace and water heater.  Frankly it looks like it's just a whole cut into the basement slab and I doubt it's been built properly.

**What are my options for retrofitting this into a proper floor drain that can take the AC condensation runoff, humidifier runoff and any possible water heater leaks?**

Here's a picture of the existing floor "drain"/hole with the current piping from the dehumidifier and furnace:
[image: Existing floor "drain"]

Comment: Can't see much in that poor photo. What makes you think the plumbing doesn't continue into the soil as it should?

Comment: Sorry for the poor picture.  That's the best my phone could do.  The PVC pipe ends about a 1/4" into the end of the hole.  There's enough play in the piping that I can lift it and shift it to the side and see down into hole.

Comment: You won't get much help because your question is too broad, and we know nothing about the rest of your plumbing system. If you're able to clarify and ask a more specific question, we may be able to help. As it is, though, it's off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm not sure how to make this any more specific.  There's no plumbing within 15 feet of the hole (I can't see under the slab but my guess is the sewer line is no closer than 10 feet at any point.  I just talked to a plumber this morning and he recommended the same condensate pump that Iggy recommended below so I'll probably go with that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Only proper options are the options. You'll need to seal that up so Radon & Water can't come in, stop the creation of a sinkhole under the house & get a condensate pump with a pipe into the plumbing or to the outdoors. Unless, you have actual real plumbing within 10 or so feet, then you may still be able to do a gravity drain or break up the floor to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  There's not real plumbing within ten feet.  I was contemplating putting in a dry well with a sump pump because of the lack of a drain.  I'll probably still consider that for emergency runoff but I'll probably add the condensate pump into the mix to avoid having the sump pump running regularly to remove the small amount of condensation or humidifier run off.

I'm not trying to dress up the hole in anyways, but fix it properly.

Comment: No, don't do anything in the floor nor beneath the floor. Regular Maintenance & Servicing will avoid any emergency situation...every 5-years is a good schedule. Condensate Water is very nasty stuff & is full of everything ever caught by your furnace filter. With a pump, you'll want to annually bleach & ream the piping & pump's catch basin to kill off the mildew & scum guys. So, put a clean-out/pour-in at the pipe beginning. They stink & leave a brown trail behind, having a sump pump handle it is therefore a very bad idea & practice. Thanks for the edit, I took it further.